The vs2022 Remote Debugger does not work on certain PCs
I am debugging a C++ Windows application using a remote debugger.
It is currently working fine in VS2013.
After upgrading to VS2022, the following message appears on certain PCs and debugging is not possible.
Error Message
The commonality of certain PCs is windows 10 pro for workstatio
Windows version
Other PCs are working fine on Windows 10 Pro.
Do you know any workaround for this?
I checked the connection and everything was fine.
When debugging with VS2022 remote debugger, after program build, deployment was successful. But when I run the deployed program, this problem occurs. It seems to happen only on a specific PC, window 10 pro for workstation.I checked the connection and everything was fine.
When debugging with VS2022 remote debugger, after program build, deployment was successful. But when I run the deployed program, this problem occurs. It seems to happen only on a specific PC, window 10 pro for workstation.
